# How to capture type of events in fields based on single event type?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

1) How to capture INFO/ERROR/WARN events using Regular expressions?

2) How to capture the rest of the events not including INFO/ERROR/WARN events using Regular expressions?

Sample log looks like this:

```
[30/07/18 17:42:00:492 XXX] 00000056 SystemOut     O 30 Jul 2017 17:42:00:492 [INFO] [xxxxxx] [] xxxxx - The total xxx is 411116 and the memory available is 2638295816.
[30/07/17 17:42:00:492 XXX] 00000056 SystemOut     O 30 Jul 2017 17:42:00:492 [ERROR] [xxxxxx] [] xxxxxxx - The total xxx is 111111111 and the memory available is 2638295816.
[30/07/17 17:42:00:492 XXX] 00000056 SystemOut     O 30 Jul 2017 17:42:00:492 [WARN] [xxxxxx] [] xxxxxx - The total xxx is 1111111 and the memory available is 2638295816.
[30/07/17 15:37:42:379 XXX] 00001db5 LdapConnectio I xxx.xxx.xx.xx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx  reCreateDirContext(String errorMessage) xxxxxxxxx The user registry is now connected to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' LDAP Server.
[30/07/17 15:33:59:281 XXX] 0000xxxx0 SystemOut O Into the constructor of xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `^.*\[(INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*$` for all

or

`^.*\[INFO\].*$` for only `INFO`

2) `^(?!.*\[(INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*).*$` for all others (this will work only for PCRE)

Comment: Hi #CrafterKolyan Thanks for the reply

Can you please give regex expression to capture those fileds in a variable something like this

xxxx(?P<name>xxxx)xxxx

caz I need to extract them like this

Comment: Modified to capture warn/info/error like  ^.*\[(?P<name>INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*$ which is working but ,when tried to capture fields not existing info/error/warn by modifying like this ^(?!.*\[(?P<name>INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*).*$  which is not working

Comment: @PrincceRajesh i think you need to use `^.*\[(?P<name>INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*$` and `^(?!.*\[(?P<name>INFO|ERROR|WARN)\].*).*$` (changed `[` to `\[` and `]` to `\]`), because actually `[` and `]` is a syntax of regex